# new modalPanel is undefined on log off script in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

Im trying to remediate an application that is currently working fine in IE6, but when running in IE8 hitting a few issues, I have managed to resolve all the other issues apart from a script error on logoff.

This is the script error on the page

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Timestamp: Wed, 28 May 2014 17:06:21 UTC

Message: 'ModalPanel' is undefined
Line: 39
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://servername/rtscscolsec/pages/common/login.jsf
```

If i run Dev Tools Script Debugger, it errors on this line.

```
<script type="text/javascript">new ModalPanel('loginForm:ajaxLoadingModalBox',
{
width: 250,
height: 50,
minWidth: 250,
minHeight: 50,
resizeable: false,
moveable: false,
left: "auto",
top: "auto",
zindex: 4000,onresize: '',onmove: '',onshow: '',onhide: '',onbeforeshow: '',onbeforehide: '',
domElementAttachment: "",
keepVisualState: false,
showWhenRendered: false,
selectBehavior: "disable",
autosized: false,
overlapEmbedObjects: false});</script>
```

Has anyone come across this issue and is there any way round it?

Any suggestion or comment on this would be appreciated

Thanks

AW

Comment: Do you have the ModalPanel code added to your page? It's not a standard JavaScript object.

Comment: there is a <script src="{urlhere}/scripts/modalPanel.js.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: just in case this sheds any more light on the subject here is the full URL    <script src="/rtscscolsec/a4j/g/3_3_3.CR1org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/modalPanel.js.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: If you browse to /rtscscolsec/a4j/g/3_3_3.CR1org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/modalPanel‌​.js.jsf, what happens?  Is the script being generated correctly?  What happens when you go to the page using Chrome or firefox?  Can you include the html that includes both the reference to modalPanel.js.jsf and the html above.